# Equating coefficients $A-2B\sin x=2-\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find out how to find $A$ and $B$ for the equation

$A-2B\sin x=2-\sin x$

I know I'm supposed to get $A=2$ and $B=\frac{1}{2}$, and I've looked on Google for help but didn't understand how any examples I found would help me solve the problem.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Equate the constant terms and solve and equate the constant on sin and solve. A = 2, -2B = -1.

Comment: By the way, you can typeset expressions using the sine function like so: "\sin x"

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation must be valid for all $x$. Since the constant function $2$ and $\sin x$, are linearly independent, it must be that the coeficients of both sides of the equation must be equal. So, $A=2$ and $-2B=-1$.

Comment: Ah, I feel very silly for asking the question now.  When I looked up "equating coefficients" on Google all I got was stuff dealing with partial fractions, which I didn't see the point of using with this problem.  Thank you for your help, I will mark this as the accepted answer when it lets me.

Comment: How do we know that the "equation" is "valid for all x"?